# anacondaでpythonのバージョンを変更する

Tags: python, anaconda

作成したアプリケーションをWeb上に公開するために、ローカルとリモートのpythonのバージョンを揃えようとしたのですが上手くいきません。anacondaに付属しているpython3.9.7を使っているのですが、リモート上のpython3.6.9にバージョンを合わせたいです。下のサイトからファイルをDL後どうすればいいのか分かりません。初歩的な質問ですが、ご教授していただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.6.9

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda付属の Python使用してるとのことなので, Anaconda (base)があるものとします。
以下はコマンドライン操作だけど, GUIでも可能なはず

- Pythonの一覧
  (`$` は UNIX系 OSのプロンプトなのでタイプの必要はない。出力との区別のため)

```
$ conda search python
(一部抜粋)
python                         3.6.7      h0371630_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.6.8      h0371630_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.6.9      h265db76_0  pkgs/main           
python                        3.6.10      h0371630_0  pkgs/main
```

- 環境作成 (ここでは 名前を `py369` とする(別の名前でも良い))

```
$ conda create -n py369 python=3.6.9
```

- 現在の環境一覧 (たぶんこんな感じのが出るはず)

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  anaconda3
py369                    anaconda3/envs/py369
```

- 普段の利用

```
$ conda activate py369

(base (3.9.7) 利用する場合)
$ conda activate base
```